# ¿Cómo obtengo un campo en especifico de una colección de documentos? firestore y python

Tags: python, firebase

estoy intentando separar una colección según 'X' campo,ya logré obtener la coleccion de documentos:

```
def getalldata():
    users_ref = db.collection(u'sample')
    docs = users_ref.stream()
    for doc in docs:
        print(u'{} => {} =>'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))

def getadocument():
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'sample').document(u'unrwWHma6tw5wAbPJ6mS')
    try:
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        print(u'Document data: iud=>{} and data: {}'.format(doc.id,doc.to_dict()))
    except:
        print(u'Nada de nada')
```

Que me devuelve:

```
 Document data: iud=>unrwWHma6tw5wAbPJ6mS and data:{'colonia': 'lejos', 'photo': 'image_picker8653987265344644941.jpg', 'estadoReporte': 'Pendiente'}
```

Pero solo necesito que me muestre un campo en especifico que es'photo'.

Comment: No he usado firebase con python. Intentaste `doc.to_dict()['photo']`?

Comment: Si, no lo había probado, gracias